# run compiled binary -> not found?

Tags: debian, sh

i am trying to run a compiled binary on my debian server.
The binary was build on another machine with the exact same OS and architecture (Debian 12, x64)

when i try to run it, i get a "not found" back.

```
/usr/src/app/bin # ls -la
total 25412
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 24 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 24 10:29 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      26003232 Jul 24 10:27 extrude_skeleton
/usr/src/app/bin # chmod +x extrude_skeleton 
/usr/src/app/bin # ./extrude_skeleton 
/bin/sh: ./extrude_skeleton: not found
/usr/src/app/bin #
```

what does this "not found" refer to?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does `file ./extrude_skeleton` report?  BTW, probably irrelevant here, but you tagged your question _bash_, but there is no bash involved.

Comment: try running with `bash extrude_skeleton` to see if there is any other output

Comment: file ./extrude_skeleton: 
`./extrude_skeleton: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=7562ad6cc675a3be254c9cd56f51ad8ceaeaeed1, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped`

Comment: bash extrude_skeleton : 
`extrude_skeleton: extrude_skeleton: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: ok, i got a littlebit closer: the problem seems to be that i am running this inside a docker container and (of course... i am stupid...) this is not debian but alpine. when i do ldd extrude_skeleton i get this error message: 
`Error relocating extrude_skeleton: __libc_single_threaded: symbol not found
`
anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: @notrev: According to the OP, `extrude_skeleton` is a **compiled binary**. Of course it can't be run in the way you are suggesting.

Comment: @HannesF : Since this is not covered by your current question, I suggest that you are writing a new question with this findings. As you haven't got any answer yet, editing the current question should also be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, what might be "not found" is the interpreter. This is mentioned in the `file` output:

```
interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

The model for running executables is that they have an interpreter, just like scripts. A `#!/bin/sh` script has a `/bin/sh` interpreter. A dynamic executable has the dynamic loader/linker as its "interpreter".

When you run `ldd` on the file inside the container, that may be a different issue. The interpreter is not required in that situation, so we move past that problem and see that there are some symbols that cannot be found.

There is no easy to way to get around building the executable for the target environment.

Executables are not portable unless they are specially designed for that (which pretty much means static). With effort, it's possible to make executables that run on multiple Unixes and Windows, like with the [Cosmopolitan](https://github.com/jart/cosmopolitan/) library by Justine Alexandra Roberts Tunney ("Jart").

> *this is not debian but alpine*

Alpine famously uses the Musl library, not Glibc. Running a Glibc executable on a Musl system isn't something you'd expect to work.

People have tried it; e.g. [this](https://github.com/gch1p/voidnsrun) project seems to provide some shim that sets up a Glibc-like filesystem namespace around a Glibc-linked program to get it to run.